# Array of all values from Table where changes occured (Oracle Apex)

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex-5

I have a table with values which is being collected from an external procedure.

```
  Name | State
  Dan  | Active
  Stan | Active
  Maggy| Inactive
```

On Apex I then have a Tabular form with select list from another Table which allows the user to update the State field. this table is as follows:

```
  STATE_ID  | STATE_NAME
  Activate  | Active
  Deactivate| Inactive
```

with a PL/SQL query in the LOV to call this field. It will then toggle the options and is displayed as:

```
  Name | State    |Set_state
  Dan  | Active   | Activate / Deactivate (in dropdown LOV)
  Stan | Active   | Activate / Deactivate (in dropdown LOV)
  Maggy| Inactive | Activate / Deactivate (in dropdown LOV)
```

This means the user can decide that Dan should be inactive and then select Deactivate from the dropdown list etc. for all the relevant names.

Now the problem I am having is the procedure from there is sent externally to a Perl script to go and do various things outside of Oracle. I therefore need to create a process that will take all the names and 'Set_State' and send it in array or list form to external script as array or to a file.

This is what I initially done, but obviously not working as :P1_NAME and :SET_STATE are the names of the columns and not the actual values. Hope I am making sense here :)

```
  DECLARE
  set_state VARCHAR2(20);
  name VARCHAR2(20);

  BEGIN

  name := :P1_NAME;
  set_state := :SET_STATE;

  mytask := 'Change_state';
  PROC(name, set_state);                < This sends Name, Set_state to below procdure
  END;
```

Please can someone help me to get the last query to contain all the values from P1_NAME and SET_STATE column when the Submit button is clicked and not just the name of the Columns. Either in array or list form.

So once I changed STAN to Inactive and Maggy to Active and button is clicked, it should send:
  Stan Inactive
  Maggy Active

to External Procedure.

This is the procedure that calls the Perl script. Not really relevant to the quesiotn, but pasting anyway.

```
  create or replace PROCEDURE "PROC" (name IN VARCHAR2, set_state IN VARCHAR2) IS

  BEGIN

  DECLARE

  BEGIN
  mytask := 'PROC';
  myscriptname := 'Script';
  dbms_scheduler.create_job(
  job_name      => myscriptname
  , job_type      => 'EXECUTABLE'
  , job_action    => '/app/proc.pl'
  , number_of_arguments => 2
  , enabled => FALSE);
  dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value(myscriptname,1,name);
  dbms_scheduler.set_job_argument_value(myscriptname,2,set_state);
  dbms_scheduler.enable(myscriptname);
  end;
  END;
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question and **highlight** what exactly it is you need help with?

Comment: Hi. In short, I need a solution in the last query that gives me all Values in the P1_NAME and SET_STATE column. Will edit question with that now.

Comment: What do you use to run the Oracle stuff, and how do you pass it to your Perl program? Can you influence what the program expects? Better yet, can you show an [mcve] of that program as well as how it's invoked?

Comment: @simbabque the last Process in the question shows the current code. The perl script is purely expecting: "Name New_state" for each entry that has changed. So if I have 300 names and change the Set_state for 200 of them, it should send a list or array of 200 to the perl script

Comment: also posted the actual Procedure that calls the perls script. this should only be called once. This means that when I edited 200 entries, it will send a list to the job and in turn will be passed to perl in array or list form.

Comment: As in `perl foo.pl Name New_state Name2 New_state2` as command line args? I don't know what Apex is or how it works. I'm from the Perl side, and I'm trying to understand how this query is run and what comes out of it, and where that goes so I can help you figure out what kind of form it would need so Perl understands it.

Comment: And lastly. This is in Apex 5.

Comment: I do not have a problem on the perl side at all. This is more Oracle apex related. I wrote the perl function and basically it will match the arguments and do something with each. So we will send "Stan Active" "Dan Active" Maggy Inactive" and perl will receive that array. and then do the relevant stuff with it. It is getting the values from Apex to perl that is the problem.

Comment: Ok. Is there no system call? So your program could be a shell script, or PHP or Python or some binary as well instead of Perl? Then you should not tag it as Perl I guess.

Comment: So the question really is _How can I send a list of data from Apex 5 to another process when the user makes changes in multiple rows within one submit?_ or something like that?

Comment: You realise `begin begin ... end; end;` is redundant, right?

Comment: Hi William, I do yes. Sorry, the script is just a portion I extracted from the real script. The rest does not really matter in this query so I did not really look at removing it. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add your tabular form query. Additionally, right now your code would call `PROC` for each row - and your job/code expects this. So what difference does it make to gather all values in an array?

Comment: @Tom. That is what I thought, but it does not. If I could get the proc to do that it would be great, but rigt now it seems to be only sending the column name to the proc :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a standard tabular form (updateable SQL Query) - NOT a classic report with `apex.item` API calls.

I'm making some assumptions about your setup because it is not 100% clear. If it doesn't match all the way it shouldn't matter too much - treat it as an example.

Query used:

```
SELECT name, state_id 
FROM states
```

Whereby:

- column `NAME`: text field, or display only with save state enabled
- column `STATE_ID`: select list, and the LOV you've used

Create an on-submit process, after validations. Make sure to associate the process with the tabular form. Set the scope to 'all created and modified rows'.
Doing this will allow you to write PLSQL which will execute in the scope of each eligible row in the tabular form. You can use bind variable syntax to refer to columns which submit their state (eg text fields, hidden items, select lists, checkboxes).
Note that "all rows" effectively means "those rows in the current pagination which has been submitted".

In this case, I can use below PLSQL to execute the process for each row which has been changed.

```
BEGIN
  PROC(name => :NAME, set_state => :STATE_ID);
END;
```

You can refer to the actual column names (headers) in bind variable syntax. Key point being that the process has to be associated with the tabular form!

*(if you don't have an actual "real" tabular form, you should point this out, and this is why I asked for the source SQL. This info matters a lot more than a lot of the other info to be found in the post!)*

Comment: Thanks a mill Tom! It seems that this will be my solution. Let me go and try it out. If I struggle I will post the sql code for you, but yes, it is an actual tabular form and not a standard or interactive report.

Comment: Hi Tom. Sorry for the delay. I managed to get it working. Your answer basically showed me that I was doing it correctly but did not get a result. I however had to change each Column field type in the Tabular form from "Plain Text" to "Plain Text (save state)" as it seemed that the plain text option displays it to the form, but does not store each value. Bottom line, it works now!

Comment: @user2082599 Right - "Plain Text" is just "Display Only" (which is the apex 4.2 terminology). "Plain Text (save state)" is still a display only, but generates an additional hidden input field - which is why I mentioned specifically "display only with save state enabled". A "Plain Text" item will not submit its state to the session, meaning it'll be empty in that plsql process. Glad you got it working!